# How can I set up a Web Stack on Windows 7?

Tags: php, web, windows-7, webserver, wamp

I have a PC running Windows 7 (Yes I know it's deprecated) with 4GB RAM and I3 Processor. I want to host a Website for my LAN. Average number of visitors would be 2-3 people. This PC is also used for daily Office Tasks like MS Excel, Browsing, etc. Is this PC feasible for a Nginx, MySQL, PHP Web Stack? Or are there any other alternative Web Stack?

Comment: If the website is only for personal use in your home network, you could just install wamp or xamp. After changing some settings and vhost on the pc it will work fine. It's even possible to host it on a cheap Raspberry pi if you whant the website to run 24/7 this use maybe alot less power then your older pc

Comment: It's for Office Work. Not a large Office, 3-4 users. But the web server would be running constantly and there will be work being done alongside on the same computer. Can I run WAMP on this Setup?

Comment: I guess your pc is fast enough for that. I run my local websites on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with the operating system on a ssd instead on a SD card and every thing works great, also the power consumtion is verry low. I also use Pihole as DNS server so I can easly created url's for my local websites when some one in my home network go to example.com I can redirect him to the IP address of my RPI 3B+.

Comment: Be prepared for hardware failure (power unit, CPU fan, harddisk) when the PC is quite old. Visually inspect the capacitors on the mainboard. Carefully remove dust if required. You may consider adding some more RAM.